# Oracle Count how many grouped items

Tags: oracle

Got this SQL:

```
select count(*), FKP_FD_RID, FKP_KEYWORD from filekeypairattib
where fkp_fd_rid > 0 and fkp_fd_rid < 1000000 
group by FKP_FD_RID, FKP_KEYWORD having count(*)>1
```

Need to know how many count() are returned? NOT how many of each group but overall count.

Can't get it right.

Comment: Running from where? From your own application you can just count the rows in the result set. In SQL\*Plus you can ask it to provide summary info. As a standalone query, do you only need the overall number of rows in the result set, or the rest of the data too? (Or are you talk ing about the sum of all the smaller counts? It doesn't sound like it but not entirely clear).

Comment: In Toad Editor...overall number of rows in the result set

Answer (score 0, accepted):

-- if you need total count as a summary of counts for each group

```
select sum(cnt) over (), s.*
from(
    select count(*) cnt, FKP_FD_RID, FKP_KEYWORD from filekeypairattib
    where fkp_fd_rid > 0 and fkp_fd_rid < 1000000 
    group by FKP_FD_RID, FKP_KEYWORD having count(*)>1
) s
```

--if you need count of lines in your original query

```
    select count(*) cnt, FKP_FD_RID, FKP_KEYWORD 
,count(*) over ()
from filekeypairattib
    where fkp_fd_rid > 0 and fkp_fd_rid < 1000000 
    group by FKP_FD_RID, FKP_KEYWORD having count(*)>1
```

Comment: Actually I did a quick and dirty CTE to get the number.